# C# Ext.net javascript html: Create a small colored box in label field

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, ext.net

I have this `label` field:

```
<ext:Label runat="server" ID="lblInfo" Text=" " />
```

I am setting the `Text` `html` property in the `Command Handler` of a `Command Column` like this:

```
<Command Handler="#{lblInfo}.setText('<i>100%: Perfect, 50%: Average, 0%: poor</i>');
```

How I can replace 100% with a green colored box, 50% with a yellow one and 0% with a red one?

Comment: Put them in `<span/>` tags that have appropriate class names, and add relevant CSS to style them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Replace '100%' with html: `<span style="background-color:green;padding-left: 50px;"></span>`
2. Replace '50%' with html: `<span style="background-color:yellow;padding-left: 50px;"></span>`
3. Replace '0%' with html: `<span style="background-color:red;padding-left: 50px;"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is perfect:

`<span style="background-color:green;padding-left: 15px;"></span> Perfect, <span style="background-color:yellow;padding-left: 15px;"></span> Average, <span style="background-color:red;padding-left: 15px;"></span> poor`